# How to use Serilog for non Host based Console Application

Tags: serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I am using below code for accessing the Serilog for non Host based Console application..I have two requirement to achieve.

I should be able to access MS extension Logger in all the other classes once Serilog is initialized.
We should be able to see the logging statement after each logging line executed..
I am using below code.

Program.cs

```
private static void main()
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        Log.Logger.Information("hello");  //it's not printing the hello in console window.
    }
```

appsettings.json

```
    "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "Async",
            "Args": {
                "configure": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Console",
                        "Args": {
                            "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
                            "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:j}{NewLine}{Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "File",
                        "Args": {
                            "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning",
                            "path": "Logs\\log.txt",
                            "rollingInterval": "Day",
                            "fileSizeLimitBytes": 10240,
                            "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
                            "retainedFileCountLimit": 30
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithExceptionDetails" ],
    "Properties": {
        "ApplicationName": "SampleApp",
        "Environment": "Int"
    }
}
```

}```

Comment: HI! Needs a lot more info about what you are trying to achieve, your current setup, etc.

Comment: See also _Serilog.Extensions.Logging_ - the samples in the repo there might be what you're after.

Comment: I have updated details @NicholasBlumhardt

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is OK.

Your code misses the call to `Log.CloseAndFlush();`
See the [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async#serilogsinksasync---).

Your code should look like below.

```
private static void main()
{
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();

    Log.Logger.Information("hello");
    
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for input .. but do we really need closeandFlush because for console app if we have written the logs at a particular line so it should logging to console window once line is executed not after calling closenadflush so that it will log at the last ..

Comment: I tend to say this one is just needed here to clear any buffered log entries. The example above is too small to show any output at runtime because the app closes immediately.

Comment: You might consider to not include the `Console` log in the `WriteTo.Async`. As the documentation - linked in my answer - says that it is mostly useful for I/O based sinks, e.g. `File` and `RollingFile`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `appsettings.json` file. The "write to console" configuration seems to be at the wrong level. Your code logs successfully to the console using this simplified version:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:j}{NewLine}{Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```